# Detect device cradled when battery is full with Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to detect whether or not a device is cradled (ie, put the device onto a charger stand).

Code below works most of the time, but it doesn't work when the battery is full and `CradleMonitorService(`) constructor is called.

```
public class CradleMonitorService
    {
        public CradleMonitorService()
        {
            IsCradled = Battery.State == BatteryState.Charging; 
            Battery.BatteryInfoChanged += Battery_BatteryInfoChanged;
        }

        public bool IsCradled { get; private set; }

        private void Battery_BatteryInfoChanged(object sender, BatteryInfoChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsCradled = (e.PowerSource == BatteryPowerSource.AC || e.PowerSource == BatteryPowerSource.Usb);
        }
    }
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Battery.PowerSource` instead to detect.

```
  public CradleMonitorService()
        {
            IsCradled = Battery.PowerSource == BatteryPowerSource.AC || Battery.PowerSource  == BatteryPowerSource.Usb
            Battery.BatteryInfoChanged += Battery_BatteryInfoChanged;
        }
```

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).